# MRenaming network interfaces based on index with WMIC and netsh with Batch

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, netsh, wmic

I have two Intel NIC's that I need to rename based on their index numbers, WMIC is nice in that it seems to always return index numbers in numerical order so we can take the output directly without needing to sort or run any comparison operations on the results.

Unfortunately I'm running into a snag where if within a FOR loop I use netsh to show interface information using a variable in the index tag it returns "Invalid index." I believe the issue is with the necessity of using back quotes in a FOR /F to switch to command processing rather than file processing. Hoping someone might be able to point out a simple mistake or give a cleaner solution to what I'm attempting to do. Code as follows:

```
SET INTERFACENAME=LAN1
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (
    'WMIC path Win32_NetworkAdapter where "Manufacturer='Intel'" get index'
) do (
    call :sub1 %%a
)

:sub1
:: %1 = index
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in (
    'netsh interface ip show interface index=%index%'
) do (
    if "%%b"=="User-friendly Name" (
        netsh interface set interface name = "%%c" newname = "%INTERFACENAME%" && set INTERFACENAME=LAN2 && exit /b
    )
)
```

The first FOR loop resolves correctly and passes an index number to the subroutine but the netsh command in the second subroutine returns Invalid index. The rest of the code in the subroutine hasn't been tested yet so I'm unsure if the INTERFACENAME variable is being updated correctly. Ideally this whole process would run through twice renaming the first result of the WMIC command to LAN1 and the second result of the WMIC command to LAN2.

Comment: Are you sure `netsh interface ip show interface index=%index%` is valid?

Comment: @Karan When I echo %index% it returns a correct integer value. If I run the command by itself with the integer value of %index% rather than the variable it behaves as expected. Not sure if that's what you mean by valid.

Comment: All I see in Win7 is `'index' is not a valid argument for this command.` Are you testing on Win8? If so the question tags might need to be edited.

Comment: Apologies I should have specified that this script is being run on Windows XP machines. On 7 & 8 i believe "index" needs to be replaced with "interface".

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken `netsh interface ip show interface interface=%index%` on Win7 doesn't include "User-friendly Name" in its output. Can you provide the exact output of the command under XP?

Comment: Here is a link to the commands output in XP redirected to a .txt file. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19h69js4lx4md0x/sample.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Just before that `if "%%b"=="User-friendly Name" (` line can you add an `echo "%%b"` and see if anything is even printed?

Comment: echo %%b produces _index._ echo %%a produces _Invalid_ I imagine if I provide an integer in place of %index% echo %%b will produce _User-friendly Name_. I'll take a stab at rewritting the script to use an integer and let you know the results.

Comment: Just discovered that I could use a ^ just before the = as a substitute for quotes as the variable expands to a value without any spaces. Unfortunately I still get the same output, but I've realized now that the index # that is being passed from the WMIC query is not the same as the index that is registered in netsh. This mismatch is causing the invalid index return as the index that is being passed by WMIC doesn't exist to netsh... uuuuugh. back to the drawing board! Thanks for taking the time to look over this.

Comment: NP, and when you do get it to work be sure to post it as an answer below, which you can self-accept as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to rewrite the script only using WMIC to query the information for the appropriate network interfaces.

The script works by querying WMI for network adapters whose ipenabled status is set to true. This weeds out all of the interfaces that are not actual ethernet adapters. We then store the first line of the output (lowest index number for an actual ethernet adapter) and pass it to a second WMI query. Which in turn utilizes the index number to obtain the netconnectionid which is the actual configured name of the adapter "IE Local Area Connection 1". We can then pass the netconnectionid to a netsh command to alter the configuration of that specific adapter. Then we pass control back to the first FOR loop via exit /b to pull up our next index number and repeat the process over again.

This can be expanded for more than two NIC's by adding more IF / ELSE comparisons after the netsh command. The NEWNICNAME value at the start will be the name applied to the lowest index. The set NEWNICNAME line after the IF / ELSE comparison will be applied the the next lowest index reported. Super amateur code as follows:

```
set NEWNICNAME=Internet
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (
    'wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where 'ipenabled^="true"' get index'
    ) do (
    set index=%%a && Call :sub1
)

:sub1
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%b in (
    'wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where index^=%index% get NetConnectionId'
) do (
    set OGNICNAME=%%b
)
netsh interface set interface name=%OGNICNAME% newname=%NEWNICNAME%
if %NEWNICNAME%==InternalLAN (
    GOTO EOL
) else (
    set NEWNICNAME=InternalLAN
)
exit /b
```

There is however a massive issue with this on XP. Documentation on renaming network adapters with netsh explicitly specifies the use of double quotes around the name and newname values. However doing so in a batch file that is not ran/called from an elevated CMD prompt for Windows XP breaks the command and returns "An interface with this name is not registered with the router". Somehow this exact same command without the double quotes will change the adapter name without issue. The problem then becomes if the NetConnectionId returns with spaces, your script will fail. This behavior is actually acceptable in my instance, as I can deploy a master image down to my fleet with both NIC's renamed LAN1 / LAN2 rather than a name with spaces. Then I perform index based reconfiguration post-deployment on the actual metal.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Sam Martin's batch script to work without delayed variable expansion.

Here's a script similar to this one that I used to set DNS servers to a specific address using
[QuickSetDNS](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/quick_set_dns.html)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Pushd "%~dp0"

goto start

:Trim
set Params=%*
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("!Params!") do EndLocal & set %1=%%b
exit /b

:exitProg
echo.
echo Operations were completed successfully for any connected network adapters.
echo.
pause
exit

:start 
echo Looking up connected network adapters...
set NICNAME=""

FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%a in (
    'wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where 'ipenabled^="true"' get index'
    ) do (
    set indexMain=%%a
    set indexMainS=!indexMain!
    set index=!indexMainS: =!
    
    set indexTrim=""
    call :Trim indexTrim !index!
    
    if not "!indexTrim!"=="" (
        REM echo Index is !index!
        Call :sub1
    )
)

goto exitProg

:sub1
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=" %%b in (
    'wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where index^=%index% get NetConnectionId'
) do (
    set OGNICNAME=%%b
    set NICNAME=!OGNICNAME!
    set NICNAMETRIM=""
    set containerStr=
    call :Trim NICNAMETRIM !NICNAME!
    if not "!NICNAMETRIM!"=="" (
        REM echo calling findstring
        echo !NICNAMETRIM! | findstr /b /l "VirtualBox">temp.txt
        set /p containerStr=<temp.txt
        del temp.txt
        REM echo containerStr is !containerStr!
        if "!containerStr!" == "" (
            echo. 
            echo Network adapter connected to the internet is named "!NICNAMETRIM!"
            echo Calling QuickSetDNS on "!NICNAMETRIM!"
            QuickSetDNS.exe /SetDNS "{IPv4_ONE_ADDR_HERE},{IPv4_TWO_ADDR_HERE}" "!NICNAMETRIM!"
            QuickSetDNS.exe /SetDNS6 "{IPv6_ONE_ADDR_HERE},{IPv6_TWO_ADDR_HERE}" "!NICNAMETRIM!"
        )
    )
)
```